# How to get arguments from url in php?

Tags: php, arrays, url

I have read some posts in stackoverflow to solve my issue partially, but I could not find the answer. `"www.site.com/?page=1&f[0]=bundle"` are the 2 arguments in my url.  `$_REQUEST['page']` works , but when I try to use `$_REQUEST['f[0]']` it does not work. I would like to skip a part of my coding based on the url. So how can I use `!isset($_REQUEST['f[0]'])` or similar test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) parameters.

```
$_GET['page']; // = 1
$_GET['f'][0]; // = bundle
```

Should work.

Comment: I used $_GET['page'] and it works when i try to use $_GET['f[0]'] it does not works. How can i get $_GET['f[0]'].

Answer (score 3):

when you pass variable with square brackets it means that this variable in PHP code will be an array. So, to get access to it use the following:

```
$_REQUEST['f'][0]
// or $_GET['f'][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

The format used to pass variables in the URL is the url itself, followed by a question mark, followed by the list of variables and variable data seperated by the amperand symbol. 
Example:

> www.domain.com/index.php?variable1Name=theFirstValue&variable2Name=theSecondValue

```
$variable1 = $_GET['variable1Name'];
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE recodrID = $variable1";
$variable2 = $_GET['variable2Name'];
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE recodrID = $variable2";
```

I should make a point right now that to be W3C valid in xhtml strict, you cannot have the & symbol anywhere in your code, instead, you must use & in the source code, which gets parsed as an amperand symbol by your browser. So if you wanted to link to the above URL example in html, the link code would look like:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/index.php?variable1Name=theFirstValue&amp;variable2Name=theSecondValue">Link Title</a>
```

i hope this helps :)

Comment: Christian's answer solved this issue. But still thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 2):

your second argument is an array, try this:

```
$_REQUEST['f'][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try this one:

```
$get_data = $_GET; // this is an array of all get parameter and value 

$pageval =   $get_data['page'];

$fval =  $get_data['f'][0];


echo $pageval;

echo $fval;
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use 3 global arrays with data from request.

$_REQUEST is common array (GET, POST, COOKIE)

$_GET - only GET-request

$_POST - only POST

So you can get f-array from request by two ways:

```
$f = $_REQUEST['f'];
print_r($f);
```

or

```
$f = $_GET['f'];
print_r($f);
```